# Error declaring typedef in header

Tags: objective-c

I created an empty class derived from `NSObject`:

```
typedef struct {
    NSInteger x;
    NSInteger y;
    NSInteger z;
}myType;

@interface MyData : NSObject {

}
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation MyData
```

I get the warning:

> No type or storage class may be specified here before 'implementation'

How can I make the typedef work correctly and also make it accessible to other classes that import the "MyData.h" header file?

Comment: What does your question title have to do with the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `@end` at the end of interface file? This is one of the possible reasons of this error.

Answer (score 0):

There's something important that you're not showing us, because this is perfectly proper code. If this is in fact your whole .h file, then I'm willing to bet that you're missing the `@end` needed to close your `@implementation` declaration.